# Push Docker Repository to Dockerhub with Jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins, docker, dockerhub

we want to push an docker repository to DockerHub - from the shell is works. But in Jenkins we get the error message `"errorDetail":{"message":"unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized"`

I think the problem is that in shell (docker login) i have to insert the email adress, login and password. In Jenkins i can only set login and password NO email.
The version of credential plugin is 1.24 and we use docker-build-step for the docker steps.

thx

Answer (score 2):

Can you have a try with the [CloudBees Docker Build and Publish plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-build-publish-plugin/blob/master/README.md)?

This plugin allows to create a build step to build a Dockerfile and publish the image into a registry (DockerHub or a private registry):

[image]

Another solution is to open a session on your Jenkins machine with the jenkins user + login to DockerHub with the relevant credentials?

With this solution, the DockerHub credentials will be cached and Jenkins should be able to push your images to the DockerHub registry.

Comment: Hi, in CloudBees Docker Build and Publish plugin we have the same problems. If you want to add some credentials we use the "Add" Button and here you can only insert username and password. Other than https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/docker-buildpublish-plugin-and-dockerfile-build-config is there no email input field...

Comment: Did you try the second solution? (open a Docker session with the command line and the relevant jenkins user)

Comment: Our docker is running in an second container and there we have testet an login and push in the shell. The docker daemon runs under root and save the information in "login credentials saved in /root/.docker/config.json" - but we get the same error.

Comment: what version of docker are you running?

Comment: Do you use Jenkins Swarm Plugin? I have a Jenkins Swarm Slave Container for this kind of task with the minimum setup costs for you. Dockerhub: blacklabelops/swarm-dockerhost

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [Docker pipeline plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) (it comes in the recommended plugins).

Jenkinsfile example:

```
node {

  checkout scm
  def dockerImage

  stage('Build image') {
    dockerImage = docker.build("username/repository:tag")
  }

  stage('Push image') {
    dockerImage.push()
  }   

}
```

Doing it this way, you must specify the credentials of the docker registry in the **Pipeline Model Definition**.

Docker pipeline plugin has problems applying the credentials assigned in Pipeline Model Definition to projects with Multi-branch pipeline. That is, if using the above code you continue to receive the error:

> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Then you must specify the credentials in the Jenkinsfile as follows:

```
node {

  checkout scm
  def dockerImage

  stage('Build image') {
    dockerImage = docker.build("username/repository:tag")
  }

  stage('Push image') {
    docker.withRegistry('https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
      dockerImage.push()
    }
  }

}
```

You can modify the URL to a custom registry if you need it